# Vue.js - Change element's class based on change to data property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue instance which has two data properties: `error` which is initially set to `false`, and `classArray` which is an object that contains two classes: `btn` and `btn-success`.

---

`btn` is set to `true` and
`btn-success` is set to `error`, which initially is `false`.

I have two `input` elements, both of which are buttons, where the first one's class is set to `classArray`.

The other button, upon clicking, invokes a method attached to my Vue instance that is supposed to toggle `error` (so if `error` is `true`, then it becomes `false`, and vice versa).

My expectation is that, because `btn-success` in `classArray` is set to the value of `error`, that upon toggling the value of `error` the corresponding class should be active on my first element.

Even though the toggling of `error` works as expected, when inspecting the first element, it doesn't appear that the `btn-success` class was added.

Is there something here I'm missing, or can you not add classes to elements like this?

Also, here is the code I'm using to test this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    error: false,
    classArray: {
      btn: true,
      'btn-success': this.error
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      this.error = !this.error;
      console.log(document.getElementById('input1'));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type='button' id='input1' :class='classArray' value='Submit' />
  <input type='button' @click='toggle' value='Change class' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the value of `btn-success` is set to true only once when the data object is first created and doesn't change after that so changing `this.error` won't have any effect on `classArray`. Instead you could set `classArray` as a computed property and it will update itself whenever `this.error` is updated.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed : {
    classArray(){
      return {
        btn : true,
        'btn-succes' : this.error
      }
    }
  },
  data: {
    error: false,
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      this.error = !this.error;
      console.log(document.getElementById('input1'));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type='button' id='input1' :class='classArray' value='Submit' />
  <input type='button' @click='toggle' value='Change class' />
</div>
```

This is just personal preference, but I personally like to use inline classes in this style (spacing for emphasis).

```
<input 
    type='button' 
    id='input1' 
    :class='["btn", error && "btn-success" ]'
    value='Submit'/>
```

Doing it this way means you can avoid adding tons of computed properties when you have a lot more elements that need variable classes.

Comment: So `classArray` is re-evaluated every time `error` changes, then?

Comment: Yep. With a compouted property Vue is aware that `classArray` depends on the value of `error` and will update it whenever error changes. [See Here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties)

Comment: Thank you for providing the reference; it's extremely helpful! Also, clever way of handling the class :)